# How can I populate this array values in html menu which have one dropdown option?

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to print this array values as my menu with this dropdown funciton.
when I am printing this array with foreach it's just printing the main array offset => value.
I need to print the sub array value in services as my dropdown option.

My array is :

```
$menuData = [
   '0' => ['Home'],
   '1' => ['About'],
   '2' => ['Contact'],
   '3' => [
      'Services' => ['Web Development', 'Wordpress', 'Mobile App'],
   ],
];
```

Here is my HTML navigation bar where I want to print the array:
The sub-array named as services will print in the dropdown option and others will be printed in the main nav-item.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($menuData as $value) { ?>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><?php echo $value[0]; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php }
                    ?>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Services
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mobile App</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

$menuData = [
    '0' => ['Home'],
    '1' => ['About'],
    '2' => ['Contact'],
    '3' => [
        'Services' => [
            'Web Development',
            'Wordpress',
            'Mobile App',
        ],
    ],
];

echo "<ul class=\"navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0\">";

foreach ($menuData as $value) {

    $menuItems = current($value);
    $isSubArray = is_array($menuItems) || false;

    if (!$isSubArray) {
        echo "<li class=\"nav-item\">
        <a class=\"nav-link active\" aria-current=\"page\" href=\"#\">";
        echo $menuItems;
        echo "</a></li>";
    } else {
        echo "<li class=\"nav-item dropdown\">";
        echo "<a class=\"nav-link dropdown-toggle\" href=\"#\" id=\"navbarDropdown\" role=\"button\" data-bs-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">";
        echo key($value);
        echo "</a>";

        echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" aria-labelledby=\"navbarDropdown\">";

        foreach ($menuItems as $item) {
            echo "<li><a class=\"dropdown-item\" href=\"#\">";
            echo $item;
            echo "</a></li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
}

echo "</ul>";
```

https://3v4l.org/toFVY

Hope it helps!